# ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, jhipster

I am trying to deploy the springboot+mysql application generated by Jhipster using docker compose. I am getting the below error in mysql when running docker logs

**ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'**

I am using like this in mysql.yml

```
environment:
        - MYSQL_USER=root
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=yes
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=jhipsterdemo3
```

And I updated application-prod.yml like this

```
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jhipsterdemo3?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: root
```

And my docker-compose.yml like this

```
jhipsterdemo3-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.20
    environment:
        - MYSQL_USER=root
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=jhipsterdemo3
    command:             mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1 --skip-ssl
        --character_set_server=utf8mb4 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
jhipsterdemo3-mysql:
image: mysql:5.7.20
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
  MYSQL_DATABASE=jhipsterdemo3
command:             mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1 --skip-ssl
    --character_set_server=utf8mb4 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

If you are using root user, you don't need to specify the user, and you are specifying a password, so allow_empty_password option should be no, which is default. Also, since you are using root user, the environment should be `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`.